# Hacer WhiteList usando cabeceras de IIS?

Tags: asp.net, webservice, iis

Necesito aplicar un filtro mediante la interfaz visual de IIS en la que sistemáticamente deniegue toda entrada a excepción de algunas cabeceras en específico.

Soy consciente de que se puede hacer a la inversa (Denegar el acceso a X cabecera).
El caso es que no encuentro ninguna opción que se contraponga a esta.

Adjunto una foto de los apartados (Con un filtro ya creado) por si alguien sabe como hacerlo.
Acaso IIS admite algo :

```
 '* <> cadena' o '* != cadena' ?
```

como cadenas de denegación?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con una funcionalidad de llamada 'Reescritura de URL" en la que se puede validar ciertas partes de la petición http pero hay muy poca información, podría usar esto para lo que necesito?
De ser así como debería hacerlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante la herramienta de Reescritura de URL se puede hacer referencias a encabezados creados anteriormente con : `{HTTP_NombreEncabezado}` y a esta asignarle un patrón (Ya sea por Regex o por una cadena en concreta)

Lo único que hay que hacer es crear una nueva regla en blanco y en el apartado "**Condiciones**" poner los parámetros por los cuales filtraremos la petición a nuestro servidor.

Así dejamos listo nuestro Whitelist usando el valor del encabezado.

(También vale para IP's, URL, variables del servidor etc...)